# Access DBF from FTP Server

Tags: ftp, dbf, clipper

I Have a application on Clipper,DBF.

### Is It Possible to access DBF file from FTP Server Using Clipper Program?

### Thanks.

Comment: If your operating system can somehow map a network drive to such location, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.

FTP is not a "shared folder". You can create a batch file which will download file via FTP, then run your clipper application, then after application finishes copy modified .DBF back to FTP server.

Note however that it will be slow (as you need to transfer whole .DBF file even if you need just a tiny bit of it) and that you **MAY NOT** use it at more than one place at a time (running it in more than one place will overwrite data, including possibility of file truncation/corruption)

There are utilities that present FTP as a filesystem ("shared folder"), for example [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net), but while it allows you to just run .exe directly instead of via aforementioned .bat file, ALL THE LIMITATIONS mentioned in previous paragraph still apply - it is not possible to avoid them due to nature of FTP.